# Нужна помощь с пунктуацией

Tags: пунктуация

Украшение в виде летающего насекомого, напоминающего осу еë тонким тельцем. Сделано из серебристо-голубого металла. Брюшко покрыто ажурным узором, а внутрь него помещён овальной формы сапфир насыщенного синего цвета. Тонкие крылышки из прозрачного и бесцветного янтаря собраны, шесть тонких лапок расставлены в виде шестиконечной звезды. Если повесить его на цепочку — оно станет подвеской, а если приложить к пальцу, то обхватив его тонкими лапками, — кольцом.

Comment: С двумя «его» проблемка: они в одной фразе, что сбивает с толку,  и первое местоимение непонятно какое существительное замещает: вариантов много.

Answer (score 2):

*Украшение в виде летающего насекомого, напоминающего **осу с еë тонким тельцем.** Сделано из серебристо-голубого металла. Брюшко покрыто ажурным узором, а внутрь него помещён овальной формы сапфир насыщенного синего цвета. Тонкие крылышки из прозрачного и бесцветного янтаря собраны, шесть тонких лапок расставлены в виде шестиконечной звезды. **Если повесить его на цепочку, оно станет подвеской, а если приложить к пальцу и обхватить лапками, то получится кольцо.***

Comment: Не пропущен предлог в «осу еë тонким тельцем»?

Comment: Пожалуй, да, спасибо. Попробую добавить.

Answer (score 1):

Украшение в виде летающего насекомого, тонким тельцем напоминающего осу, сделано из серебристо-голубого металла. Овальный сапфир насыщенного синего цвета помещен в брюшко, покрытое ажурным узором. Изящные прозрачные крылышки собраны из бесцветного янтаря, шесть тонких лапок расставлены в виде шестиконечной звезды. Если повесить украшение на цепочку, то это будет подвеска, а если обхватить лапками палец — кольцо.

**Объяснения**
Тут дело не только в пунктуации.
Четыре раза слово "тонкий" — это перебор.
Брюшко покрыто ажурным узором, а внутрь него помещён сапфир. В брюшко или в узор?
[Обхватить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — охватить, плотно прилегая, облегая.
"Приложить" — лишнее.

Comment: (1) Если это технический текст, то не надо дробить его на детали, а потом строить из них свои  предложения.  (2) Причастие «напоминающее» желательно расположить после определяемого слова. (3) «Изящные» вместо «тонких» не дают нужной информации. (4) Точность касается и последнего предложения о способах использования украшения, так как текст не сразу воспринимается на слух.